# Optimal Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure looks something like:

```
id, parent_id,......
```

Sample Data in table:

```
id  parent_id
1   null
2   null
3   1
```

I want to fetch rows and its matching parent row.
The output will be:

```
id parent_id
3  1
1  null
```

What will be the most optimal mysql query for this

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results *in a tabular format*.

Comment: have added sample data

Answer (score 0):

The query you want would appear to be:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1 in (t.id, t.parent_id);
```